# How to use onConfigurationChanged() in android 2.3.3 version

Tags: android-layout

I overided onConfigurationChanged() in android 2.3.3 version. When I changed Land-Scape to Portraint, its orientation is changed but from Portrait to Landscape it is not changing.
Please help me to change the orientation from Portrait to Landscape.

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        int orientation = this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

        if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            setContentView(R.layout.settings);
        } else if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            setContentView(R.layout.settings);
        }


    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566305/orientation-is-not-working-in-2-3-3  - Related. Seems like an issue only with the emulator http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13189

Answer (score 0):

[Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566305/orientation-is-not-working-in-2-3-3)

Ensure that the Manifest has following entry for the activity you are launching.

```
  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden
```

On the emulator, it might happen that once you change the orientation, it will not go back to the previous one because of [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13189)