# orientation is not working in 2.3.3?

Tags: android, android-orientation

I have prepared one application.My application will be supports both landscape and portrait.
 When i change the orientation from portrait to landscape it is working fine,But when i change landscape to portrait it is not working.my code is,

```
  public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        System.out.println("orientation---"+getResources().getConfiguration().orientation);
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            System.out.println("landscape-----");
        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            System.out.println("portrait-----");
        }

    }
```

Every time time it taking only landscape mode.I made mistake some where. please help.

```
System.out.println("orientation---"+getResources().getConfiguration().orientation);
```

The above SOP is printing 2 means landscape.Please help me.(i am using 2.3.3)

Comment: The same code once check in 2.3.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be hitting this bug **"Orientation does not change from landscape to portrait on Emulator on 2.3"**

More than 45 people are facing the same issue with the androidd 2.3 emulator

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13189

> Host OS: Windows 7 SDK tools version : revision 8 Eclipse version: 3.5
>   ADT plug-in version: 8.0.1 Platform targeted by your project: 2.3
>   Version of the platform running in the emulator:2.3
>
> **STEPS TO REPRODUCE:**
>   1. Activity 1 (no screen orientation) -     Activity 2 (screen orientation = landscape)
>
> 1. Going from Activity 1 to 2 works fine. Pressing back changes the orientation of Activity 1 to landscape
>
> **EXPECTED RESULTS:** Activity 1 should be in portrait mode
>
> **OBSERVED RESULTS:** Behavior is observed only in gingerbread, works as
>   expected on froyo.

Comment: ya i have added "configChanges" attribute to manifest file like this "android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden""

Comment: Please provide us more information, if you have android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden it should work fine. Add more code.

Comment: @Soham: Poster is telling that onConfigurationChanged is called. Please tell us how it is possible without specifying android:configChanges="orientation" in android manifest.

Comment: Thank u so much Soham...It is working fine for all version expect 2.3.3. I have checked all versions.Please check once in 2.3.3.Please help me

Comment: Ahaa, look at this bug filed on AOSP - "Orientation does not change from landscape to portrait on Emulator on 2.3" About 45 ppl reported it, it seems to be a common problem :) http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13189 Can you try running it on a real device with 2.3.3?

Comment: That explains why the same code works on every other version except 2.3

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with the `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` .

if you remove `|keyboardHidden` from the androidmanifest.xml, then the onConfigurationChanged is only fired when you rotate from landscape to portrait, not when you go from portrait to landscape (at least in the default emulator).

Hope this helps.

**EDIT: DID some sample program to test it and works fine for me.**

**CheckOrientationActivity.java**

```
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CheckOrientationActivity extends Activity {


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second_layout);
        Log.i("DayElevenActivity", "onCreate Start");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        Log.i("DayElevenActivity", "onConfigurationChanged");
        // Checks the orientation of the screen
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            Log.i("ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE", "ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE");
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            Log.i("ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT", "ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT");
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

In **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"   
            android:configChanges="**orientation|keyboardHidden**"    
            android:name=".CheckOrientationActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

**Corresponding Logs when i run and change the orientation**

```
03-05 18:54:31.644: I/CheckOrientationActivity (20314): onCreate Start
03-05 18:54:35.014: I/CheckOrientationActivity (20314): onConfigurationChanged
03-05 18:54:35.014: I/ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE(20314): ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
03-05 18:54:41.984: I/CheckOrientationActivity (20314): onConfigurationChanged
03-05 18:54:41.984: I/ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT(20314): ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
```

Comment: I remove "|keyboardHidden " from manifest file and run the application when i change the orientation from landscape to portrait or portrait application is automatically closing.

Comment: Edited my answer. Please check the same. Works fine for me.

Comment: Thank u so much Deva...It is working fine for all version expect 2.3.3. I have checked all versions.Please check once in 2.3.3.Please help me

Comment: did u check with 2.3.3 emulator?

Comment: yes the issue is there on 2.3.3 emulator. Don't have a real 2.3.3 device to validate it on a real device.

Answer (score 1):

There's multiple reasons why this could happen, hard to tell without seing more code.

Here's some pointers:

- you haven't forced the layout to some particular orientation via manifest file or programatically (something like `<activity android:screenOrientation="portrait">` in your manifest)
- by default the Activity is restarted when configuration changes happend. If you want to NOT have your activity restarted when the orientation changes, you need to use

  android:configChanges="orientation"

on your activity's configuration in the manifest.

- the above point will in fact make Android call your activity's `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration)` method when the orientation changes

==update==

Also, if you have the same layout (like "main") declared in layout-land and layout-port you only need to specify that you want to use that layout in the beginning:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
```

and that's it. THERE IS NO NEED to also implement the

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  //...
}
```

method as well. For the sake of chosing the correct layout based on orientation all you have to do is declare the same layout in those two folders.

(Also, there is NO NEED to add the  `android:configChanges="orientation"` to your manifest, apparently it's on by default). I've tried all this just now, works ok

Comment: Well,ok, but I see that you set the exact same layout for either of the 2 orientations. Try making two different layouts for vertical and horizontal and switch the appropriate one when the orientation changes. This will rearrange the widgets in your view.

Comment: i have prepared two layouts for landscape and portrait.All landscape layouts placed in layout-land folder in res and all portrait layouts placed in layout-port folder in res

Comment: what is the problem is "getResources().getConfiguration().orientation" is returns always 2(means landscape)

Comment: try calling newConfig.orientation instead of getResources().getConfiguration().orientation

Comment: Please once see my code.I have used both thing in different places.

Comment: I've seen your code. What I see is that you call "getResources().getConfiguration().orientation" in the if/else. Try replacing those calls with "newConfig.orientation" where newConfig is the argument from the "onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) method"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8536/discussion-between-chiru-and-andrei-bodnarescu)