# Why is my Orientation Change Going Unnoticed?

Tags: java, android-manifest, android-orientation, onconfigurationchanged, android-configchanges

Based on the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726657/how-to-detect-orientation-change-in-layout-in-android), I added this code to an Activity as what I hoped to be the first step in changing the assigned Layout for an Activity:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings_landscape);
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    }
}
```

...and modified the Activity's element in AndroidManifest.xml. e.g., changing it from this:

```
<activity
    android:name="hhs.app.SettingsActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" >
</activity>
```

...becomes this:

```
<activity
    android:name="hhs.app.SettingsActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" >
</activity>
```

(I added the "configChanges" jazz).

But, although mashing keypad.9 does indeed flip the orientation in the emulator, no toast is being raised (the breakpoint on the "if" line of onConfigurationChanged() is not being hit). What am I doing wrong or omitting?

Note: It made no difference when I removed "|keyboardHidden" from the "configChanges" line in AndroidManifest (it was just a hunch - I wondered if it meant "pay no attention to an orientation change made via the keyboard").

### UPDATE

I tried araut's suggestion, and also the one from Jared Burrows [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726657/how-to-detect-orientation-change-in-layout-in-android), but neither one works for me.

Cold this be simply an emulator problem? I have no device to test it with yet, so I can't empirically answer that question myself.

### UPDATE 2

Based on what I read [here](http://www.androidadb.com/source/eyes-free-read-only/ocr/ocrservice/src/com/googlecode/eyesfree/ocr/intent/CameraManager.java.html), I thought maybe adding some OrientationEventListener jazz would solve this dilemma, but no!

This is the code I added (shown in context; what's new is the OrientationEventListener stuff):

```
public class SettingsActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private OrientationEventListener mOrientationListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        . . .

        mOrientationListener = new OrientationEventListener(getApplicationContext()) {
            @Override
            public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
                Toast tostadaOrient = Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, 
orientation, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                tostadaOrient.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                tostadaOrient.show();
            }
        };
        mOrientationListener.enable();
    }
```

...but I still get no reaction (no toasts are raised from here or the onConfigurationChanged() event).

Comment: Did you try: android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"

Comment: I did now, but it makes no difference.

Comment: Are you using old emulator? Please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566305/orientation-is-not-working-in-2-3-3

Comment: I doubt that it's an old emulator, as it wasn't that long ago that I installed Droidio (Android Studio), but how can I tell what version the emulator is?

Comment: @Heyyou - I probably didn't, or I would have updated the post with a description of how I did. But it's been so long ago (over a year), and I haven't worked in Java/Android since, that I really can't recall.